# Jumping out of Frame issue in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, frames, frameset

For some reason the right frame keeps jumping out of the frame set. When the frame is run independently, it works fine....

here is the URL: http://www.linkwell.info/test/

Answer (score 0):

What's with the "script" fragment floating around outside the `<html>` tag in the left frame? You've got that script and a stray `<body>` tag before the opening `<html>` tag. That's not good.